# How not to show 0 with IF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my excel function. I don't know how to change the IF sentance to not include 0's if they are in a certian column.

Tried nesting them like in programming languages but it did not work.

```
=AG2
    & "-"
    & D2
    & IF(LEN(F2)<=2;F2;"")
    & IF(F2="0";"";)
    & IF(F2="3XL";"XXXL";)
    & IF(F2="4XL";"XXXXL";)
    & IF(F2="5XL";"XXXXXL";)
    & IF(F2="6XL";"XXXXXXL";)
    & IF(F2="XXL";"XXL";"")
```

I don't seem to know how to post a cleaner version of the formula.

unedited:

```
=AG2 & "-" & D2 & IF(LEN(F2)<=2;F2;"") & IF(F2="0";"";) & IF(F2="3XL";"XXXL";) & IF(F2="4XL";"XXXXL";) & IF(F2="5XL";"XXXXXL";) & IF(F2="6XL";"XXXXXXL";) & IF(F2="XXL";"XXL";"")
```

Comment: Please clarify your objective and provide sample input/output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition for the length of F2 needs to be nested into the condition to see if F2 is zero.

```
=AG2
 &"-"
 &D2
 &IF(F2="0"; ""; IF(LEN(F2)<=2; F2; ""))
 &IF(F2="3XL";"XXXL";)
 &IF(F2="4XL";"XXXXL";)
 &IF(F2="5XL";"XXXXXL";)
 &IF(F2="6XL";"XXXXXXL";)
 &IF(F2="XXL";"XXL";"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
=AG2 & "-" & D2 & IF(F2=0; ""; IF(AND(IFERROR(FIND("XL"; UPPER(F2)); FALSE); ISNUMBER(VALUE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(F2); "XL"; ""))))); REPT("X"; VALUE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(F2); "XL"; ""))))&"L"; F2))
```

To break this down we can look at it in chunks. The first part is obvious

```
AG2 & "-" & D2
```

Takes the values from Cells `AG2` and `D2` and combines them with a `-` separator.

The next part produces the output from cell `F2`

```
IF(F2=0; ";
```

This tests whether cell `F2` is equal to `0` and if so returns an empty string.
The next condition we test for if `F2` contains an `XL` and if so is there a number in the cell as well.

```
IFERROR(FIND("XL"; UPPER(F2)); FALSE)
```

Tests if `F2` has `"XL"` in the value

```
ISNUMBER(VALUE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(F2); "XL"; ""))))
```

Tests whether there is a number included as well
If both the conditions above returns `True` then the formula repeats the letter `"X"` the number of times of the number in cell `F2` and combines it with an `"L"` on the end

```
REPT("X"; VALUE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(F2); "XL"; ""))))&"L"
```

e.g. this will convert

```
2xl -> XXL
3xl -> XXXL
4xl -> XXXXL
5xl -> XXXXXL
6XL -> XXXXXXL
7XL -> XXXXXXXL
etc.
```

For anything else (e.g. `""`, `S`, `M`, `L`, `XL`, `XXL` etc.) it will return those values unmodified. This should cover all of your examples above and more (if needed)